# How to send the total amount of an order to Stripe Api using Asp.Net Core MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, stripe-payments, gateway

I have a Shopping Cart project developed in Visual Studio I am implementing the stripe gateway but I am not sure how to send the total amount of an order to Stripe, all the examples online is showing the amount typed rather than collecting the total of the shopping cart from a list of items and then send the total to stripe:

[Order with Total to be sent to Stripe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1uYJ.png)

and

[Stripe checkout without the total](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtFkg.png)

```
  <div class="caption">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                    <h3>Shopping Cart Payment</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 price">
                    <h3>                       
                        @Model.Total.ToString("c")
                    </h3>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <p></p>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-product"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> Like</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">

                                            <button id="pay-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-success  btn-product"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Pay with Card</button>
```

this is my method in the stripe controller to call the checkout:

```
 public ActionResult Custom()
        {
            string stripePublishableKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["stripePublishableKey"];
            var model = new CustomViewModel() { StripePublishableKey = stripePublishableKey, PaymentFormHidden = true };
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
        public ActionResult Custom(CustomViewModel customViewModel, string token, int amount)
        {
            customViewModel.PaymentFormHidden = false;
            var chargeOptions = new ChargeCreateOptions()
            {
                //required
                **Amount = amount,**// how to add the total for the order here?** 
                Currency = "euro",
                Source = token,
}
```

I tried the below:

```
var amount = _appDbContext.ShoppingCartItems.Where(c => c.ShoppingCartId == ShoppingCartId)
                    .Select(c => c.Pie.Price * c.Amount).Sum();
                return total;

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
        public ActionResult Custom(CustomViewModel customViewModel, string token)
        {
            customViewModel.PaymentFormHidden = false;
            var chargeOptions = new ChargeCreateOptions()
            {
                //required
                **Amount = amount,
                Currency = "euro",
                Source = token,
}
```

My doubt is how do I post the total amount of my order to Stripe for the customer to pay with the credit card?

Comment: Can you edit your question to reduce your code example to the minimum required to demonstrate the issue? Also, please add some of the things you've tried, and how they worked out.

Comment: I just edit the question is it clear now? rather then using the embed form from stripe I am using the custom form.

Comment: This looks pretty close, Devs. Currency should be set to "EUR" not "euro" and the Amount should be cents. If `total` here is 51.85, then you would pass the int 5185 as the Amount.

Comment: @w1zeman1p I would like to pass a function or a lambda expression to work with all the shoppingcart usually people put example as the below:

Comment: That's fine, I just mean Amount needs to be set to an integer value. That can be returned from your db call or another function.

Comment: Stripe Payment Integration in Asp.net Web Forms and its 100 percent  working code and you can also download application 
https://code2night.com/Blog/MyBlog/Implement-Stripe-Payment-Gateway-In-ASPNET